# How do I listen to a http call in a service from a component in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

I am just starting off with angular and I need some help regarding listening to new http calls in a service from a component. Initially, I fetch data(returns an array) from an api call through ngOnInit from `content.component.ts` using `fetch-article.service`
Later when updateID is called by another component (`sidebar.component.ts`) it calls the same function from `fetch-article.service`. What I want to do is as soon as a new http request is made from fetch-article.service, the `items` variable in `content.component.ts` should have the value of newly fetched data.

content.component.ts:

```
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {
  items = [];

  constructor(
    private fetchArticlesService: FetchArticlesService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getArticlesbyID('123')
    .subscribe(result => {
     console.log('test')
  });

  getArticlesbyID(id){
  return this.fetchArticlesService.fetchArticles(id).pipe(map(
    fetchArticlesService => {
      this.items = Object(fetchArticlesService);
    })
  )}
}
```

In my fetch-article.service.ts, I have:

```
export class FetchArticlesService {

  fetchArticles(id) {
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/query/' + id);
  }

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }
}
```

sidebar.component.ts:

```
updateID(id) {
    this.fetchArticlesService.fetchArticles(id)
  }
```

Please help me out on this. I am just getting started with Angular.
Stackblitz code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vyotee

Comment: So the current problem is? Unable to achieve it?

Comment: Yes. When I render it in html, the value of 'items' variable remains the same even after the fetchArticles() function is executed in the service.

Comment: Can you provide Stackblitz code where I can reproduce

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vyotee
When I click the button, new data should be displayed.

Comment: I found two component, Button in Sidebar component.And Content in Content Component.If button click has to update content, either shared service or emitting  id from sidebar component has to be done

Comment: Please check my answer - it also has working stackblitz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A subscription to HTTP module means that once you get the response, the subscription is finished and destroyed by default. Therefore your current logic will never work. One more problem that I saw was here

```
updateID(id) {
    this.fetchArticlesService.fetchArticles(id)
  }
```

> To execute the observable you have created and begin receiving
>   notifications, you call its subscribe() method, passing an observer.

In other words, this method will never trigger as observable requires to be subscribed to in order to trigger it. Read more about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/observables)

The solution for your problem is to create another observable ([Subject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Subject)) and then subscribe to that one:

```
export class FetchArticlesService {
  public articles: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  fetchArticles(id) {
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/query/' + id).pipe(
      map((result) => {
         this.articles.next(result);
      }));
  }

}
```

Now in your component in order to call the API and load the observer you just created with new data, you have to do this:

```
this.fetchArticlesService.fetchArticles(id).subscribe();
```

And in your `content.component.ts` or any other component as well, you have to subscribe to `articles`. That's how you can 'update' the response data in multiple places automatically.

```
this.fetchArticlesService.articles.subscribe((res) => console.log(res));
```

**Check the solution here:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-edotfc

**IMPORTANT:** When ever you 'kill' the component which has that subscription, it is also important to stop the subscription to prevent the memory leak. However, if your component is alive all the time (such as navigation bar, sidebar, and components of that type), it is not necessary to do it. The best way would be to destroy it inside the [ngOnDestroy](https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy)

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.fetchArticlesService.articles.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Understood what was going wrong!

Answer (score 2):

Have you been introduced to Subjects in angular? I think this is an ideal case for subject.

Subjects are observables themselves but what sets them apart is that they are also observers. What does that mean? It means that a subject can emit data, on top of having the capability to be subscribed to.

Defining a subject (in the fetch-article-service): `let fetchSubject= new Subject<string>();`

Emitting a data (passing the id from sidebar): `fetchSubject.next("Eureka");`

Subscribing to the changes in subject: `fetchSubject.subscribe((data) => {
  console.log("Subscriber got data >>>>> "+ data);
});`

Based on the id that you receive, you can make the http call there. The result can be passed to the subject which will pass it on to all the subscribers. For this particular case, you might need to work on the flow a little bit.

The rough flow that I can visualize is that you can pass the result of the http call in the subject by using the subject.next. As soon as the data in the subject is changed, it will notify the new data to wherever you may want to use it. Hope this may be useful for you.

Comment: What I want is, as soon as the http call is made, the newly fetched data should be updated in the content-component. I am able to make the http call but I am not able to update the variable from response from the call in the content-component. Can you please provide a small example?

Comment: The answer to this question has been mentioned by @dino. Please refer his code. That is exactly how I would have done it too.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this picture of your stackblitz. You need to make sure a subscriber receives an http request, and from there assign the result to the variable needed.

[image]

Comment: And how do I listen for new http requests from the content component?

Comment: can I save the stackblitz? so that I can show you? Also you need to pass the this.item variable from content component if you want it to be updated. Or make an Observer.

Comment: Go ahead please. You can make the necessary corrections and save it.

Comment: this is a nice answer too as an event emitter. But I think in the long run, Subjects and Observables are better. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mi4zlm

Comment: Yes, I believe this could be a easy way. Better way could be having a Shared service with subjects.

Comment: this is the nice answer by #Dino https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-edotfc

Comment: @AbishekramR Thanks for the solution. I feel, using subjects is the better way to go